# How to get frame sync signal from a GoPro Dual HERO System sync cable?

Tags: binary-analysis, hardware, firmware, dynamic-analysis

I need to frame sync a GoPro Dual HERO System with an external data logger. So the main problem is to get the HERO frame synchronization signal (I guess there must be one in the cable) from their system. Can someone help here?

I guess some degree of reverse engineering could be done just by listening to the cable wires when both cameras capture synced video? I am a very new to electronics so please excuse my simplicity. There is a forum thread about [GoPro Dual Hero cable reverse engineering](http://goprouser.freeforums.org/gopro-dual-hero-cable-reverse-engineer-t19093.html).